# How do I mount single files using ansible?

Tags: ansible, docker-container

I've got a directory on my remote host that I want to mount into a docker container. The issue with this directory is, that its files and itself need a specific owner and group. First, I've tried:

```
    ...some code...

        - name: setup jitsi-meet volumes
          file:
            path: "{{ item }}"
            state: directory
            owner: 999   # jvb / jicofo in videobrige / jicofo container
            group: 1000  # jitsi in videobrige / jicofo container
            mode: 0755
          with_items:
            - "{{ CONFIG }}/jicofo"
            - "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb"

    ...some code...

        # Video bridge
        - name: run jitsi-meet jvb image
          docker_container:
            name: jitsi-jvb
            ........
            volumes:
              "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb:/config"
            ........

    ...some code...
```

Ansible does create the volumes recursively with the required owner and group. So `{{ CONFIG }}/jvb` and its content have `999:1000` (`jvb:jitsi`). However, for whatever reason, during mounting only `/config` has the required owner and group (`999:1000` or `jvb:jitsi`) while the content of `/config` still has `root:root`. Then, I've tried to mount file by file (see below), but ansible refused to let me do this. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
# Video bridge
- name: run jitsi-meet jvb image
  docker_container:
    name: jitsi-jvb
    ..........
    volumes:
      "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb:/config"
      "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb/logging.properties:/config/logging.properties"
      "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb/sip-communicator.properties:/config/sip-communicator.properties"
```

The error was:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
did not find expected key

The error appears to have been in '/FAKEPATH/docker-container-jitsi.yml': line 56, column 7, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

      "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb:/config"
      "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb/logging.properties:/config/logging.properties"
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: this is the resulting issue https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet/issues/5 .. but i need to ssh as root into the remote machine. Running the container as regular user is not an option ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a simple syntax problem to me.
The dashes for your volumeList are missing:

```
...
volumes:
 - "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb:/config"
 - "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb/logging.properties:/config/logging.properties"
 - "{{ CONFIG }}/jvb/sip-communicator.properties:/config/sip-communicator.properties"
...
```

Comment: For further reference: this answer solved my question but not the issue itself. To set owner and groups of these special images belonging to those containers in a correct way, a different approach is necessary. Either run the image as regular user or - if this is not possible - change the permissions manually, restart the containers, extract the files (logging.properties and sip-communicator.properties) to your local machine and include a copy task in your .yaml file with the required owner/group values. If you run the images now, they won't create those files because they're already there.